# « Faire du ball-trap » au figuré ?

Tags: sens, sport, emprunts

> — Paris essaye d'intercepter le missile avec un tir balistique.
>  —
>   Ils ont déjà testé ce dispositif ? [L'amiral]
>  — Non.
>  — Ils font du
>   *ball-trap*. Je déteste le *ball-trap*. [L'amiral]
>
> [ Extrait de dialogue dans *Le chant du loup* (2019, Abel
>   Lanzac/Antonin Baudry) ]

Le [*ball-trap*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ball-trap) c'est un emprunt pour le dispositif projecteur ou [appareil de lancement](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18046474) servant à placer en l'air les pigeons d'argile au tir du même nom ([*tir aux pigeons d'argiles*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=9472505)). À [*pigeon*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pigeon) on trouve au TLFi l'exemple :

> [...] Mais, pour le tir
>   d'entraînement, le ball-trap (...), on n'utilise que les «Pigeons»
>   d'argile, petits disques creux, noirs parfois cerclés de blanc,
>   fragiles au point qu'un seul plomb les brise. (Burnand, T., au TLFi)

Il semble que par métonymie ça désignerait le *tir d'entraînement* lui-même.

Dans le dialogue c'est une simple comparaison avec ce type d'activité vu l'idée d'interception ou y a-t-il d'autres connotations ; est-ce qu'on peut comparer à ou désigner généralement quelque chose comme *faire du ball-trap* et qu'est-ce que ça voudrait dire ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est en effet une métonymie ici.
Ici les militaires essayent d'intercepter les missiles (les pigeons d'argile) avec un tir balistique (une balle de fusil, un plomb).

Je n'ai jamais entendu / ne me suis jamais servi du *ball-trap* comme moyen de désigner quelque chose d'autre. C'est cependant un bon outil de comparaison / pour une métonymie car l'idée d'interception / viser quelque chose au vol peut-être apppliquée à de nombreuses situations.

Par exemple, on pourrait parler de *faire du ball-trap* si l'on cherche à toucher un ballon avec un autre (pour le dévier de sa trajectoire par exemple).

Comment: Est-ce encore une métonymie alors que *ball-trap* est déjà employé beaucoup plus couramment comme nom de l'activité que du dispositif technique qui la rend possible (il existe par exemple une Fédération français de ball-trap, qui organise ce sport et non la collection des ces dispositifs) ?

Comment: C'est une bonne remarque. Il est vrai que l'on utilise de moins en moins le terme "tir au pigeon", et de plus en plus "ball-trap".